# @import "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"; not working in Angular 17+

Tags: angular, animate.css

if i use @import "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css";

in my styles.scss I encounter the following Error:

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css" [plugin angular-compiler]

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.3",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.2.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.4"
  },
```

I sucessfully installed animate.css as you can see in my dependencies.

I included

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"
            ],
```

I tried

```
@import '~animate.css/animate.min';
```

I also tried to import per link href in my index.html

None of those work for me

Comment: `~` is a webpack thing, remove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
npm i animate.css
```

In Angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/global_styles.css",
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"
         ]
```

**OR**

In global_styles.css

```
@import "animate.css";
```

To check, simply in .html

```
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounceOutLeft">Hello World!</h1>
```

NOTE: Always we change the angular.json or install a new npm package, we need re-start the server.